# Is it possible to sort in a filter?

Tags: odoo

Hello I want to create a filter with "Group By create_date", and "Sort By adquat_num_machine_related" (my field),

I succeed to group by, but not to sort

I tried to sort in a Group by item :

[image]

And i tried to sort in a Favorites item:
[image]

I found 'order' in context on the web
I tried to use 'order' in context it seems it do nothing

Is this possible ? Thanks

Comment: "I tried" - and what happened next, and why was that not the result you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to group by and it works

Comment: I want to group by + sort, and if i tried to use 'order' in context it seems it do nothing

Comment: Is that what you want to filter is a list view?

Comment: If so there is an attribute `default_order ` can add on tree tag.

Comment: but I'm not sure whether it can work with group-by or not.

Comment: Yes I saw default_order on tree tag but it is for all user ? I want it for 1 user

Answer (score 1):

Try using _order in py file for sort and add filter in your search view or you can add default_order in tree view for sort records.

Comment: Yes I saw _order and default_order ,  but it is for all users ? I want it for 1 user

Comment: @Kishiro try adding attribute to specific user group.

Comment: So I do xpath on the tree i want (position attributes), i add default_order->my field and groups_id->my group right ?

Comment: @Kishiro also try inheriting tree view and add groups in view define your attributes there.